# Create querydsl predicate from map

Tags: spring-data, querydsl

I need help creating a predicate to use with Spring data and querydsl. I'm in the process of converting Daos to Repositorys. And I came across one that has a dynamic query in it. I can create a predicate from a list, but I'm lost at how to create a a dynamic predicate from a map. Here is the code from the DaoImpl that I'm converting from:

```
    public Set<String> getDocumentsByDocumentAssociation(Map.Entry<String,String>[] associations) {
String queryStr = "SELECT da FROM DocumentExternalAssocEntity as da WHERE";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(queryStr);

    //loop through inputs.  for first loop, skip appending the OR statements.  Append OR for all others
    for ( int i = 0; i < associations.length; i++ ){
        if ( i > 0 ) {
            sb.append(" OR");
        }
        String whereString = " (da.associationtype = :docAssocType" + i + " AND da.associationvalue = :docAssocValue" + i + ")";
        sb.append(whereString);
    }

    //query when previous loop is done appending
    final Query query = em.createQuery(sb.toString());        
    for( int i = 0; i < associations.length; i++ ) {
        query.setParameter("docAssocType" + i, associations[i].getKey());
        query.setParameter("docAssocValue" + i, associations[i].getValue());
    }
```

And here is the relevant generated class:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1971644089L;

public static final QDocumentExternalAssocEntity documentExternalAssocEntity = new QDocumentExternalAssocEntity("documentExternalAssocEntity");

public final StringPath associationtype = createString("associationtype");

public final StringPath associationvalue = createString("associationvalue");
```

Thanks, and let me know if you need any additional info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
BooleanExpression expr = null;
for ( int i = 0; i < associations.length; i++ ){
    BooleanExpression innerExpr = 
        documentExternalAssocEntity.associationtype.eq(associations[i].getKey())
            .and(documentExternalAssocEntity.associationvalue.eq(associations[i].getValue()))
    if (expr == null) {
        expr = innerExpr;
    } else {
        expr = expr.or(innerExpr);
    }
}
```

Comment: for aggregation you can also use `BooleanBuilder`.